# Dialog getting destroyed on orientation change

Tags: android

I have two classes one adapter and one activity, i have a dialog in my adapter , amd iam calling this adapter in my activity , when i change the orientation when my dialog is up ,dialog is getting destroyed .i tried

```
<activity android:name=".activity.SearchAttraction" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" />
```

and

```
    @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        }
   Noting is working, getting error at line `dialog.show();`    

public void performAction(View v, Activity activity) {

        Context myContext = v.getContext();
        PopUpMenu popUpMenu = (PopUpMenu) v.getTag();
        String result = popUpMenu.getMenuName();
        if (result != null
                && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.savecurrentlocation))) {
            getCurrentLocation();

        }
        // For Manage Menu..
        else if (result != null
                && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.addnewplace))) {
            AttractionData attractionData = new AttractionData();
            createDiloag(attractionData,
                    activity.getResources().getString(R.string.addnewplace));
            this.activity.finish();

        }
        // For About Us..
        else if (result != null
                && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.fromaddressbook))) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(activity, ProfileActivity.class);
            callIntent.putExtra("ProfileType", Constants.FROM_CONTATCS);
            Log.d(TAG, "start to call On Activity Result Method : ");
            parentActivity.startActivityForResult(callIntent, 100);
            Log.d(TAG, "end to call On Activity Result Method : ");
            this.activity.finish();

        }

        else if (result != null
                && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.distancebetween))) {
            AttractionService service = AttractionService
                    .getInstance(parentActivity.getApplicationContext());
            ArrayList<AttractionData> allMenuSearchList = service
                    .getAllAttractions(true, Constants.field, Constants.order);

            if (allMenuSearchList != null && !allMenuSearchList.isEmpty()) {

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pickdestination);
                ListView listPlace = (ListView) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.listPlace);
                PlaceAdapter placeAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(parentActivity,
                        allMenuSearchList, R.layout.pickcity, dialog,
                        R.string.pickstartingpoint, null);
                listPlace.setAdapter(placeAdapter);
                dialog.show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(parentActivity, R.string.nonavigationtolink,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            this.activity.finish();
        }
```

this is my log

```
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity org.app.mycity.activity.ABActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420c3948 that was originally added here
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:412)
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:312)
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at org.appright.myneighborhood.adaptor.AddressPopUpAdapter.performAction(AddressPopUpAdapter.java:169)
01-30 16:38:31.690: E/WindowManager(2791):  at org.appright.myneighborhood.adaptor.AddressPopUpAdapter$1.onClick(AddressPopUpAdapter.java:93)
```

i am struck, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please learn about the Activity life cycle.  You will need to understand this to be successful with any Android app.  See onPause() and onResume() in particular.  You should dismiss your dialog in onPause() and recreate it (if required) in onResume()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic assumption,

I think, `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` is not called when you change the orientation, Just check it by debug or by putting log inside it.

The parameters

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

are not sufficient in Android 4.0+

Try with other parameters in `android:configChanges` in **activity tag** of manifest file.

Something like,

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize"
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: yes onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) is not being called..any other solution?